# Find law of linear combination of random vectors

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X, Y$ be independent centered Gaussian random variables with variance $1$ and $a,b$ be real constants. Is it possible and how would one in general compute the law of the gaussian vector $(aX-bY,bX+aY)$?

Comment: You cannot even find the distribution of $aX-bY$ or $bX+aY$ let alone their joint distribution.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You could if they were independent

Comment: Of course. But is is serious error to simply assume independence when that is not given.

Comment: X and Y are independent, sorry about the omission @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(aX-bY,bX+aY)$ has  a two dimensional normal distribution. All you have to do is to find the variance covariance matrix (since the means are both $0$). $Var (aX-bY)=a^{2}+b^{2}$, $Var (bX+aY)=a^{2}+b^{2}$ and $cov((aX-bY,bX+aY))=ab-ab=0$.